# WPF 3D transparent textures - clipping?

Tags: wpf, textures, transparent, clipping

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZNdfVwkttM - you can see all of the problem described on this video if you can't see pictures.

All of walls in all images below have a semitransparent PNG texture. Each square wall, floor and ceiling tile is a separate GeometryModel3D (I know that is no good for performance but...). The floor and the ceiling of the central cube have no any geometry and textures - so they have a color the same as Window.Background (black). But the effect considered appears in any way of transparency obtaining: texture for ImageBrush with transparency, Material.Color (for example DiffuseMAterial.Color) where Color has alpha channel, ImageBrush as material where ImageBrush has Opacity - all the way I have the same problem.

All of walls consists of two triangles. Where are no explicit normals , because I define triangle indices so normals culculated automatically by WPF.

http://imagepost.ru/images/i/ma/image00001.png

It also haven't any back material or extra triangles from the back side.

As you can see there is no problem if you look only from +Z to -Z (standing on the blue square and looking to the red square - that is the second picture).

But if you look backward (from red to blue - the first picture) there is no transparency!

Well, I desided to look from the yellow square (third picture).

And then I walked nearer - you can see what was happening (pictures from 4 to 6).

There are no geometry construction error or texture mapping error or lighting error! It is some kind of clipping, I guessed! In addition there are some interested pictures 7 and 8 to prove my guess.

The last picture shows the white background of the window that hosted Viewport3D (previous was black), and my guess about clipping confirmed - WPF just not painted this part of the scene and we can see the window background!

BUT! If this happens from various looks, why the look from +Z to -Z (second picture) seems well?!

Comment: Additional images:   http://imagepost.ru/images/i/ma/image00003.png   
http://imagepost.ru/images/i/ma/image00004.png   
http://imagepost.ru/images/i/ma/image00005.png   
http://imagepost.ru/images/i/ma/image00006.png   
http://imagepost.ru/images/i/ma/image00007.png   
http://imagepost.ru/images/i/ma/image00008.png   
http://imagepost.ru/images/i/ma/image00009.png

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943067/wpf-3d-textures-with-alpha-channel/6331933#6331933 Can the Z-order be the reason of this WPF behavior? And how to escape this?

Comment: Hi there, in getting 403 access denied (forbidden) on all images. Also if I were you, I'd edit you answer to remove swearing before an admin down votes you

Comment: Just reload them by pressing Enter in the adress bar of the browser - I have the same 403 and after reloading they appear.

Comment: And the second picture http://imagepost.ru/images/i/ma/image00002.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sort the triangles based on their distances from the viewpoint. Only then, wpf will be able to blend the transparent textures.
DirectX is able to blend triangles on top of each other but only when drawing them back to front

http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/2_Transparency.html

Comment: It can be only added that it is enough to sort transparent models in order from far to near to the point of view. At least as I understood.

Comment: No, not when a transparent triangle is visible in front of an opaque triangle.

Comment: Well, and how about to sort only the whole models in Model3DGroup.Children collection, but not to sort every triangle in the scene? The second way is too difficult and bad for performance.

Comment: "when a transparent triangle is visible in front of an opaque triangle" - You try to say that in this case I needn't to sort triangles (or models)? But how about this case http://www.imagepost.ru/?v=0001_20.png I need to sort them because the transparent edges which you can see on the picture. Each creature on this picture is a rectangle (consists of many triangles) with texture with transparent background. But if I sort them from far to near of my camera look direction these artifacts will go away.

Comment: "But how about this case imagepost.ru/?v=0001_20.png" - The walls on this picture are not transparent and are located behind of the transparent objects.

Comment: You need to sort the triangles when it is possible that a transparent triangle that is closer by is draw first. This case will never be drawn correctly. Only when you are certain that the triangles of a model never overlap you do not have to sort them. When solid triangles are in the background you need to draw those first an then draw the sorted transparent triangles.