# WPF 3D and texture with cutouts

Tags: wpf, 3d, transparency

I have WPF 3D model and texture with cutouts. No translucency, just 1 or 0 for color alpha value. And I have an issue with mesh drawing order. But in XNA I'm solved this problem with using clip() in my shader and sorting is no longer necessary. Is there any "cutout-mode" in WPF?

Comment: You know that XNA can be used in conjunction with WPF, right?

Comment: Right. But it not clean solution. My editor is very simple and WPF has enough features to get what I can get in XNA. Now the only problem is that through the "holes" in textures cannot be seen other meshes, if mesh with "holes" were drawn before other. In XNA it looks correct, but it prevents while editing.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to order the triangles or meshes back to front when drawing.

Comment: Does it mean only way is lumped all my meshes together in one big triangle heap and reorder them each time camera or model moves? It's... sad :(

Comment: No, you can keep the triangles in their own meshes as long as the meshes do not intersect. WPF was never meant for things like this. If this is really important to you, you might want to switch to a different API such as SlimDX

Comment: Probably rendering finally should be produced with XNA or SlimDX, or some other API. If WPF 3D is so pure, it's not an option to continue use it.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700822/wpf-3d-transparent-textures-clipping (might be a duplicate)

Comment: No. In my case each pixel can be opaque or totally transparent. I think I'll try same solutions as in XNA.