# WPF: overlaying 3D tiles and transparency

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, transform, transparency

I have been trying to get WPF 3D tiles with transparency to work for interlocking tiles that need to transform and rotate in 3D space. It works (see code) but where tiles overlap, the underlying tile is covered by opaque colour where it should be visible. I have read articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700822/wpf-3d-transparent-textures-clipping) but this uses objects that are transparent in their entirety and state that you need to look at the order in which to draw with the transparent objects drawn last, but how would that work with two or more interlocking shapes that all have to be partially transparent?
Here's code. I have tried two variants, one using meshes and one using visuals but both show the same behaviour. Note that the tiles are very thin but have a front and back.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp4.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp4"
    xmlns:PresentationOptions="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/options" mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Mesh Test" Width="550" Height="300" ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered"
    PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="viewbox" TargetType="{x:Type Viewbox}">
      <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform" />
      <Setter Property="StretchDirection" Value="Both" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="200" />
      <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="viewport3d" TargetType="{x:Type Viewport3D}">
      <Setter Property="ClipToBounds" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="Height" Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
      <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="1" />
      <Setter Property="RenderOptions.EdgeMode" Value="Aliased" />
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid Background="DarkGreen">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="viewboxTiles1" Style="{StaticResource viewbox}">
      <Viewbox.Effect>
        <BlurEffect x:Name="viewboxTilesEffect1" Radius="0.0" />
      </Viewbox.Effect>
      <Viewport3D x:Name="viewport3DTiles1" Style="{StaticResource viewport3d}">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
          <PerspectiveCamera Position="0,0,.87" LookDirection="0,0,-1" FieldOfView="60" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport3D.Children>
          <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
              <DirectionalLight x:Name="directionalLightTilesLeftBottom1" Color="White"
                  Direction="-0.612372, -0.612372, -0.612372" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
          </ModelVisual3D>
          <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
              <DirectionalLight x:Name="directionalLightTilesRightBottom1" Color="White"
                  Direction="0.612372, -0.612372, -0.612372" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
          </ModelVisual3D>
          <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
              <DirectionalLight x:Name="directionalLightTilesLeftTop1" Color="White"
                  Direction="-0.612372, 0.612372, -0.612372" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
          </ModelVisual3D>
          <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
              <DirectionalLight x:Name="directionalLightTilesRightTop1" Color="White"
                  Direction="0.612372, 0.612372, -0.612372" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
          </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D.Children>
      </Viewport3D>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="viewboxTiles2" Style="{StaticResource viewbox}">
      <Viewbox.Effect>
        <BlurEffect x:Name="viewboxTilesEffect2" Radius="0.0" />
      </Viewbox.Effect>
      <Viewport3D x:Name="viewport3DTiles2" Style="{StaticResource viewport3d}">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
          <PerspectiveCamera Position="0,0,.87" LookDirection="0,0,-1" FieldOfView="60" />
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport3D.Children>
          <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
              <DirectionalLight x:Name="directionalLightTilesLeftBottom2" Color="White"
                  Direction="-0.612372, -0.612372, -0.612372" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
          </ModelVisual3D>
          <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
              <DirectionalLight x:Name="directionalLightTilesRightBottom2" Color="White"
                  Direction="0.612372, -0.612372, -0.612372" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
          </ModelVisual3D>
          <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
              <DirectionalLight x:Name="directionalLightTilesLeftTop2" Color="White"
                  Direction="-0.612372, 0.612372, -0.612372" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
          </ModelVisual3D>
          <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
              <DirectionalLight x:Name="directionalLightTilesRightTop2" Color="White"
                  Direction="0.612372, 0.612372, -0.612372" />
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
          </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D.Children>
      </Viewport3D>
    </Viewbox>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace WpfTestApp4 {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        private const int GeometryTilesCountX = 4;
        private const int GeometryTilesCountY = 1;
        private readonly NameScope _objNamescope = new();
        private readonly Storyboard _storyboard;
        private bool _bStoryboardPaused = false;

        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            NameScope.SetNameScope(this, _objNamescope);
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            _storyboard = new() {
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)),
                AutoReverse = false,
                RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
            };
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            BuildTiles(true);
            BuildTiles(false);

            _storyboard.Begin(this, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace, true);
        }

        private void BuildTiles(bool bUseMesh) {
            Random rnd = new();
            string strNumber = bUseMesh ? "1" : "2";
            int iCounter = 1;
            List<CustomTile> customTiles = new();
            for (int iTileX = 0; iTileX < GeometryTilesCountX; iTileX++) {
                for (int iTileY = 0; iTileY < GeometryTilesCountY; iTileY++) {
                    DependencyObject dependencyObject;
                    GeometryModel3D? gm = null;
                    Viewport2DVisual3D? v2dv3d = null;
                    MeshGeometry3D mg = new() {
                        TriangleIndices = new Int32Collection() { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 },
                        Positions = new Point3DCollection() {
                            new Point3D(-0.5 + (iTileX / 2) * 0.5, -0.75, 0),
                            new Point3D(0.0 + (iTileX / 2) * 0.5, -0.75, 0),
                            new Point3D(0.0 + (iTileX / 2) * 0.5, 0.75, 0),
                            new Point3D(-0.5 + (iTileX / 2) * 0.5, 0.75, 0)
                        }
                    };
                    if (bUseMesh) {
                        gm = new GeometryModel3D();
                        dependencyObject = gm;
                        RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(gm, EdgeMode.Aliased);
                        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(gm, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
                        _objNamescope.RegisterName("graphNamePrefixGeoPart" + iTileX + iTileY + strNumber, gm);
                        mg.TextureCoordinates = new PointCollection() { new Point(-1, 1), new Point(0, 1), new Point(0, 0), new Point(-1, 0) };
                    } else {
                        v2dv3d = new Viewport2DVisual3D();
                        dependencyObject = v2dv3d;
                        RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(v2dv3d, EdgeMode.Aliased);
                        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(v2dv3d, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
                        _objNamescope.RegisterName("graphNamePrefixGeoPart" + iTileX + iTileY + strNumber, v2dv3d);
                        mg.TextureCoordinates = new PointCollection() { new Point(0, 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 0), new Point(0, 0), };
                    }
                    _objNamescope.RegisterName("_graphNamePrefixMeshPart" + iTileX + iTileY + strNumber, mg);
                    DiffuseMaterial? dmf = null;
                    DiffuseMaterial? dmb = null;
                    if (bUseMesh && gm != null) {
                        gm.Geometry = mg;
                        dmf = new(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent));
                        EmissiveMaterial dmfs = new(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) { Opacity = 1.0 });
                        Viewport2DVisual3D.SetIsVisualHostMaterial(dmf, false);
                        gm.Material = new MaterialGroup() { Children = { dmfs, dmf } };
                        dmb = new(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent));
                        EmissiveMaterial dmbs = new(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent) { Opacity = 1.0 });
                        Viewport2DVisual3D.SetIsVisualHostMaterial(dmb, false);
                        gm.BackMaterial = new MaterialGroup() { Children = { dmbs, dmb } };
                    } else if (!bUseMesh && v2dv3d != null) {
                        v2dv3d.Geometry = mg;
                        dmf = new();
                        Viewport2DVisual3D.SetIsVisualHostMaterial(dmf, true);
                        v2dv3d.Material = new MaterialGroup() { Children = { dmf } };
                        Image rectangle = new() {
                            Width = 1.0,
                            Height = 1.0,
                            IsHitTestVisible = false,
                            Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
                        };
                        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(rectangle, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
                        v2dv3d.Visual = rectangle;
                    }
                    Transform3DGroup tfg = new();
                    RotateTransform3D rtf3d = new(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), 0));
                    _objNamescope.RegisterName("_graphNamePrefixGeoPart_graphNameSuffixRotateTransform3D" + iTileX + iTileY + strNumber, rtf3d.Rotation);
                    tfg.Children.Add(rtf3d);
                    TranslateTransform3D ttf3d = new(new Vector3D(0, 0, 0));
                    _objNamescope.RegisterName("_graphNamePrefixGeoPart_graphNameSuffixTranslateTransform3D" + iTileX + iTileY + strNumber, ttf3d);
                    tfg.Children.Add(ttf3d);
                    if (bUseMesh && gm != null) {
                        gm.Transform = tfg;
                        viewport3DTiles1.Children.Add(new ModelVisual3D { Content = gm });
                    } else if (!bUseMesh && v2dv3d != null) {
                        v2dv3d.Transform = tfg;
                        viewport3DTiles2.Children.Add(v2dv3d);
                    }

                    // Do stuff with the created tiles
                    CustomTile customTile = new();
                    customTile.Init(new Point(iTileX, iTileY), new BitmapImage(new Uri(Enter_Pic_Filename_Here + iCounter + @".png")),
                        GeometryTilesCountX, GeometryTilesCountY,
                        customTiles.Where(t => t.HomePos.X == (iTileX - 1) && t.HomePos.Y == iTileY).FirstOrDefault(),
                        customTiles.Where(t => t.HomePos.X == iTileX && t.HomePos.Y == (iTileY + 1)).FirstOrDefault(),
                        new Pen { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gold), Thickness = 0.5 }, true, false);
                    customTiles.Add(customTile);
                    if (customTile.GeometryDrawingGroup != null) {
                        if (bUseMesh && dmf != null && dmb != null) {
                            DrawingGroup drawingGroup = customTile.GeometryDrawingGroup;
                            drawingGroup.OpacityMask = customTile.OpacityMask;
                            dmf.Brush = new DrawingBrush(drawingGroup) { Opacity = 1.0, };
                            drawingGroup = drawingGroup.Clone();
                            GeometryDrawing geometryDrawing = (GeometryDrawing)drawingGroup.Children[0];
                            geometryDrawing.Pen = new Pen { Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Thickness = 0.5 };
                            drawingGroup.OpacityMask = customTile.OpacityMask;
                            drawingGroup.ClipGeometry = customTile.ClipGeometry;
                            dmb.Brush = new DrawingBrush(drawingGroup) { Opacity = 1.0, };
                        } else if (!bUseMesh && v2dv3d != null) {
                            DrawingGroup drawingGroup = customTile.GeometryDrawingGroup;
                            drawingGroup.OpacityMask = customTile.OpacityMask;
                            Image rectangle = (Image)v2dv3d.Visual;
                            rectangle.Source = new DrawingImage(drawingGroup);
                            rectangle.Clip = customTile.ClipGeometry;
                        }
                    }
                    Rect rect = new(
                        (-0.5 +
                            -customTile.ProtrusionEdgeSizes.Left / GeometryTilesCountX +
                            (double)iTileX / GeometryTilesCountX) * 1.0,
                        (-0.5 +
                            -customTile.ProtrusionEdgeSizes.Bottom / GeometryTilesCountY +
                            (double)iTileY / GeometryTilesCountY) * 1.0,
                        (1.0 + customTile.ProtrusionEdgeSizes.Left + customTile.ProtrusionEdgeSizes.Right) * 1.0 / GeometryTilesCountX,
                        (1.0 + customTile.ProtrusionEdgeSizes.Top + customTile.ProtrusionEdgeSizes.Bottom) * 1.0 / GeometryTilesCountY);
                    double dblZ = 0.0;
                    mg.Positions = new Point3DCollection() {
                        new Point3D(rect.Left, rect.Top, dblZ),
                        new Point3D(rect.Right, rect.Top, dblZ),
                        new Point3D(rect.Right, rect.Bottom, dblZ),
                        new Point3D(rect.Left, rect.Bottom, dblZ)
                    };

                    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new() {
                        From = 0.0,
                        To = rnd.Next(360, 720),
                        Duration = _storyboard.Duration,
                    };
                    Storyboard.SetTargetName(doubleAnimation, "_graphNamePrefixGeoPart_graphNameSuffixRotateTransform3D" + iTileX + iTileY + strNumber);
                    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(AxisAngleRotation3D.AngleProperty));
                    _storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);

                    iCounter++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Key == Key.P) {
                if (_bStoryboardPaused)
                    _storyboard.Resume(this);
                else
                    _storyboard.Pause(this);
                _bStoryboardPaused = !_bStoryboardPaused;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomTile {
        public class ProtrusionEdgesStruct {
            public double Left { get; set; }
            public double Top { get; set; }
            public double Right { get; set; }
            public double Bottom { get; set; }
            public override string ToString() { return Left.ToString() + "," + Top.ToString() + "," + Right.ToString() + "," + Bottom.ToString(); }
        }

        public static Point GetPointOffset(Point pt, double X, double Y) { return new Point(pt.X + X, pt.Y + Y); }
        public static CroppedBitmap? GetCroppedBitmap(BitmapSource bitmapSource, int iX, int iY, int iWidth, int iHeight) {
            if (iWidth == 0)
                iWidth = 1;
            if ((iWidth + iX) > bitmapSource.PixelWidth)
                iWidth = Math.Max(1, bitmapSource.PixelWidth - iX);
            if (iHeight == 0)
                iHeight = 1;
            if ((iHeight + iY) > bitmapSource.PixelHeight)
                iHeight = Math.Max(1, bitmapSource.PixelHeight - iY);
            Int32Rect int32Rect = new(iX, iY, iWidth, iHeight);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Bitmap size=" + bitmap.PixelWidth + "x" + bitmap.PixelHeight + ", croppedBitmap rect: " + int32Rect);
            CroppedBitmap? croppedBitmap = null;
            try {
                croppedBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(bitmapSource, int32Rect);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("GetCroppedBitmap: cropped bitmap error " + ex.Message + ", bitmap w x h=" + bitmapSource.PixelWidth + " x " + bitmapSource.PixelHeight + ", rect=" + int32Rect);
            }
            return croppedBitmap;
        }

        private Point _homePos;
        public Point HomePos {
            get { return _homePos; }
            private set { _homePos = value; }
        }

        public CroppedBitmap? Bitmap { get; private set; } = null;
        public ProtrusionEdgesStruct ProtrusionEdgeSizes { get; set; } = new();
        public Brush? OpacityMask { get; private set; } = null;
        public DrawingGroup? GeometryDrawingGroup { get; private set; } = null;
        public Geometry? ClipGeometry { get; private set; } = null;

        public virtual void Init(Point homePos, BitmapSource bitmapSource, int iTileCountX, int iTileCountY, CustomTile? tileNeighbourLeft, CustomTile? tileNeighbourTop,
        Pen pen, bool bSwapYDirection, bool bCalculateAverageColor) {
            _homePos = homePos;
            // Only the right and bottom edges are needed, left and top are defined by adjacent tile
            ProtrusionEdgesStruct protrusionEdgeSizes = new();
            double dblTileBitmapWidth = bitmapSource.PixelWidth / (iTileCountX == 0 ? 1.0 : iTileCountX);
            double dblTileBitmapHeight = bitmapSource.PixelHeight / (iTileCountY == 0 ? 1.0 : iTileCountY);
            // Create a combination of the path figures outline geometry with the ellipses for the protrusions
            ProtrusionEdgeSizes = protrusionEdgeSizes;
            double dblProtrude = 20.0;
            protrusionEdgeSizes.Left = dblProtrude / 30.0;
            protrusionEdgeSizes.Right = dblProtrude / 30.0;
            PathFigure pathFigure = new() {
                IsClosed = true,
                IsFilled = true,
                StartPoint = new Point(0, 0)
            };
            pathFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(30, 0), true));
            if (homePos.X != 3)
                pathFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(30 - dblProtrude, 15), true));
            pathFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(30, 30), true));
            pathFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(0, 30), true));
            if (homePos.X != 0)
                pathFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(new Point(-dblProtrude, 15), true));
            PathGeometry pathGeometry = new() { Figures = { pathFigure } };
            CombinedGeometry combinedGeometryCut = new() {
                GeometryCombineMode = GeometryCombineMode.Intersect,
                Geometry1 = new RectangleGeometry(pathGeometry.Bounds),
                Geometry2 = pathGeometry,
            };
            Bitmap = GetCroppedBitmap(bitmapSource,
                (int)(Math.Max(0.0, HomePos.X - protrusionEdgeSizes.Left) * dblTileBitmapWidth),
                (int)(Math.Max(0.0, bSwapYDirection ? iTileCountY - 1 - HomePos.Y - protrusionEdgeSizes.Top : HomePos.Y - protrusionEdgeSizes.Top) * dblTileBitmapHeight),
                (int)(dblTileBitmapWidth * (1.0 + protrusionEdgeSizes.Left + protrusionEdgeSizes.Right)),
                (int)(dblTileBitmapHeight * (1.0 + protrusionEdgeSizes.Top + protrusionEdgeSizes.Bottom)));
            Bitmap?.Freeze();
            GeometryDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
            GeometryDrawingGroup.Children.Add(new GeometryDrawing() {
                Pen = pen ?? new Pen() { Brush = Brushes.Transparent, Thickness = 0.0 },
                Brush = new ImageBrush(Bitmap),
                Geometry = combinedGeometryCut,
            });
            OpacityMask = new DrawingBrush() {
                Opacity = 1,
                Drawing = new GeometryDrawing() {
                    Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                    Geometry = combinedGeometryCut,
                }
            };
            ClipGeometry = combinedGeometryCut;
        }
    }
}
```